# how to solve calculations in java

Tags: java

I'm working on a calculator, it should receive the input as a String and then perform the calculation, outputting the result.

For example, the input could be

> ```
>   ((23+17) mod 7 × 4 AND 13
> ```

and the output would be `4`, as expected.

How can I parse the input, to extract all the operands and perform the calculation ?

Comment: Do you know that there exists the modulo operator in Java? Look for it..

Comment: I would suggest using math to solve such calculations.  Also, it's really important here, if you are trying to do this, to formalize what `AND` represents.

Comment: Are you comfortable with the Java Language?

I assume not. Probably less effort could have been spent in finding the answer on google.

Comment: I think he's asking how to parse that input string and produce a result.

Comment: yes, the problem is that I receive the input as a String and I don't really know how to parse it

Comment: @wasp256 Check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13798557/java-expression-parser-calculator-shunting-yard-algorithm

Comment: Maybe overkill, but contains a chapter about parsing expressions: http://www.pearsonhighered.com/educator/product/Compilers-Principles-Techniques-and-Tools/9780321486813.page

Comment: OP - What have you already tried?

Comment: @wallace nothing yet, I was asking for the best way to parse the string...

Comment: Go and get a book on compiler theory and read the chapter on how parsers work.  A really good answer to this question would run for several pages; and it's not really suitable for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other answers are just "how to set a variable to this result" but if you're actually looking to parse input, you should refer to this:

[Equation (expression) parser with precedence?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28256/equation-expression-parser-with-precedence)

There are a number of ways to go about solving this kind of problem, and a number of algorithms for doing so.  Some of them are stack based, some perform a descent of the "tree", and I can even think of a (somewhat) convoluted way to OOP-ize it.  I would start with the link above.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expressions to parse the string.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

First you have to look for the most important arguments like [() - parentheses], then less [*/] and [+-]. You have to divide the whole string into parts.

Examples:

[Simple calculator (bottom of the page)](http://stevenrbrandt.com/cios/index.php/Regex.xml)

[Another calculator](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/236807-regex-use-for-a-simple-calculator-app/page__st__15)

Both in Java.

Comment: can you elaborate? The language is not regular (note for example nested parenthesis) so I don't see how you could do that?

Answer (score 0):

see this page for your reference.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_basic_operators.htm

all operators in java are explained very clearly.

Comment: I know about the logic operators I have to handle a string