# How to make an efficient expression calculator?

Tags: java

How to make the code read multiple operands in the expression entered by the user.

If i have to read them how to find the different operators and operands here is the code for basic expression calculator made by me which is able to read the expression and evaluate only one operand and two operators

**e.g.**
If input is 2+3
it will give me 5.0 as result

 **but**
if input is 2 + 3, i.e with space it gives no output at all how to make it work correctly even in case of a space.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Calc {

public static void main(String args[]){

    int j=0;

    float op1=0,op2=0,result=0;

    Scanner inp=new Scanner(System.in);

     System.out.println("Sir,Please enter the expression");

     String exp1=inp.next();

     String exp = exp1.replaceAll(" ","");

      for(int i=0;i<exp.length();i++){

         if(exp.charAt(i)=='+'||exp.charAt(i)=='-'||exp.charAt(i)=='*'||exp.charAt(i)=='/'){

           if(exp.charAt(i)=='+'){

                   i=j;

                   op1=Float.parseFloat(exp.substring(0, j+1));

                   op2=Float.parseFloat(exp.substring(j+2,exp.length()));

                   result=op1+op2;

                   System.out.println(result);

                   break;
             }

             if(exp.charAt(i)=='*'){

                   i=j;

                   op1=Float.parseFloat(exp.substring(0, j+1));

                   op2=Float.parseFloat(exp.substring(j+2,exp.length()));

                   result=op1*op2;

                   System.out.println(result);

                   break;

             }

             if(exp.charAt(i)=='-'){

                   i=j;

                   op1=Float.parseFloat(exp.substring(0, j+1));

                   op2=Float.parseFloat(exp.substring(j+2,exp.length()));

                   result=op1-op2;

                   System.out.println(result);

                   break;
             }

             if(exp.charAt(i)=='/'){

                   i=j;

                   op1=Float.parseFloat(exp.substring(0, j+1));

                   op2=Float.parseFloat(exp.substring(j+2,exp.length()));

                   if(op2==0){

                       System.err.println("Division by zero is not possible");

                       break;

                   }

                   else{

                      result=op1/op2;

                      System.out.println(result);

                      break; 
                   }

             }
         }


     }

}

}
```

Comment: do you like to make a calculator which calculates on the strings like 2+3-5*2 etc?

Comment: yes i would like to make such a calculator

Comment: see my answer to the question

Comment: Note that `new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("JavaScript").eval("2+3-5*2");` does the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey Chris ideally it should work now but still its not working now can you tell me what to do i have modified the replacAll statement can you please check it out.

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Calc {

public static void main(String args[]){

```
int j=0;

float op1=0,op2=0,result=0;

Scanner inp=new Scanner(System.in);

 System.out.println("Sir,Please enter the expression");

 String exp1=inp.next();

 String exp = exp1.replaceAll("\\s","");    //It will replace all the spaces from the string

  for(int i=0;i<exp.length();i++){

     if(exp.charAt(i)=='+'||exp.charAt(i)=='-'||exp.charAt(i)=='*'||exp.charAt(i)=='/'){

       if(exp.charAt(i)=='+'){

               i=j;

               op1=Float.parseFloat(exp.substring(0, j+1));

               op2=Float.parseFloat(exp.substring(j+2,exp.length()));

               result=op1+op2;

               System.out.println(result);

               break;
         }

         if(exp.charAt(i)=='*'){

               i=j;

               op1=Float.parseFloat(exp.substring(0, j+1));

               op2=Float.parseFloat(exp.substring(j+2,exp.length()));

               result=op1*op2;

               System.out.println(result);

               break;

         }

         if(exp.charAt(i)=='-'){

               i=j;

               op1=Float.parseFloat(exp.substring(0, j+1));

               op2=Float.parseFloat(exp.substring(j+2,exp.length()));

               result=op1-op2;

               System.out.println(result);

               break;
         }

         if(exp.charAt(i)=='/'){

               i=j;

               op1=Float.parseFloat(exp.substring(0, j+1));

               op2=Float.parseFloat(exp.substring(j+2,exp.length()));

               if(op2==0){

                   System.err.println("Division by zero is not possible");

                   break;

               }

               else{

                  result=op1/op2;

                  System.out.println(result);

                  break; 
               }

         }
     }


 }
```

}

}

Answer (score 0):

If you're only looking to stop spaces from interfering with your evaluation, just remove them:

**Example**

```
String expression = "2 + 2";
String parsedExpression = expression.replaceAll(" ", "");

// Evaluate.
```

**Edit for the sake of pedant-ism**

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter an expression and hit enter: "); 
String expression = s.readLine();

String parsedExpression = expression.replaceAll(" ", "");
```

Comment: will this code is going to remove spaces between the string the user have entered?

Comment: Its not working its giving no output at all on executing

Comment: This will convert `2 + 2` into `2+2`. Here's an example of it working:http://ideone.com/dl5u3D

Comment: @ Chris the solution you gave works perfect for this scenario but what would happen when the expression to be calculated changes?

Comment: Well this was just an example.. Obviously it's a pretty simple step to allow the user to change the input..

Comment: @Chris it's not working its just showing the first operator and nothing else even when i tried to print the modified string.

Comment: I have edited it in my code do you want me to post the edited code?

Comment: That's.. what i meant.

Answer (score 0):

if you are looking to perform calculations on the string having multiple operators and operands like "2+3-5*4+2*sin(45)" then you need to study about parsing an infix to RPN(reverse polish notation)

Shunting yard algorithm is one such way to accomplish complex calculations through efficient parsing.

I cant find very much java related material for the same as I am a c# developer. But, i have implemented the same in one of my windows phone projects and it works.

Few links which I could provide you at this point of time.

[Java Expression Parser & Calculator Shunting Yard Algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13798557/java-expression-parser-calculator-shunting-yard-algorithm)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm

http://andreinc.net/2010/10/05/converting-infix-to-rpn-shunting-yard-algorithm/

With this I am attaching some operator and their precedence rules in c# 
See the stack overflow link i have mentioned above and then study what I wrote below.

```
            OPERATORS.Add("+", new int[] { 0, LEFT_ASSOC });
            OPERATORS.Add("-", new int[] { 0, LEFT_ASSOC });
            OPERATORS.Add("*", new int[] { 5, LEFT_ASSOC });
            OPERATORS.Add("/", new int[] { 5, LEFT_ASSOC });
            OPERATORS.Add("%", new int[] { 5, LEFT_ASSOC });
            OPERATORS.Add("^", new int[] { 10, RIGHT_ASSOC });
            OPERATORS.Add("Sin", new int[] { 10, RIGHT_ASSOC });
            OPERATORS.Add("Cosh", new int[] { 10, RIGHT_ASSOC });
            OPERATORS.Add("Sinh", new int[] { 10, RIGHT_ASSOC });
            OPERATORS.Add("Tanh", new int[] { 10, RIGHT_ASSOC });
            OPERATORS.Add("Cos", new int[] { 10, RIGHT_ASSOC });
            OPERATORS.Add("Tan", new int[] { 10, RIGHT_ASSOC });
            OPERATORS.Add("Log", new int[] { 10, RIGHT_ASSOC });
            OPERATORS.Add("ln", new int[] { 10, RIGHT_ASSOC });
            OPERATORS.Add("Sqrt", new int[] { 10, RIGHT_ASSOC });
            OPERATORS.Add("Floor", new int[] { 10, RIGHT_ASSOC });
            OPERATORS.Add("Ceil", new int[] { 10, RIGHT_ASSOC });
            OPERATORS.Add("Square", new int[] { 10, RIGHT_ASSOC });
```

Comment: Sir i have no idea about c# can you help me for some java solution please.

Comment: I have added one more link in the answer to help you out check it(I hope it helps)! That's only I could do sitting here. You would need to implement the algorithm yourself. I made a calculator for windows phone using the same algorithm implementation in c# check this link-http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/make-maths-easy/9d4634f0-ac82-49d3-920a-74f3af4d3a0a.

Comment: All the best, The method works for sure, Sorry but I couldn't make my hands dirtier on this.